# Color line under color name in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, settings

There was a time when I saw actual color as a thick line under color name in Visual Studio. Now I can see it only once as its blinks after I finish writing color name. Is there a way how see those color lines permanently?

[image: Missing color line]

I really do not know how to describe it better and probably therefore google gives me results I do not find usefull.

This is the desired result (now it shows only when I type).

[image: Desired color]

//Ok I found on some pages it is visble on some it is not... Any idea what can be cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because you were using a "Visual Studio Extension" like this - [Color highlighter for CSS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Smoria.ColorhighlighterforCSS)

Also its very much recommended to get the **Web Essentials** Extension for your VS which includes a lot of cool additions to your front end development in VS. More can be read [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsefulVisualStudioExtensionWebEssentialsFromMadsKristensen.aspx)

If your interested, here is a link to the [WebEssentials 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebEssentials20153)

**Update:**
There is also been an issue where "Web Essentials 2015 extension keeps getting disabled" on VS restart. [Here is a step-by-step solution to it](https://david.gardiner.net.au/2015/11/web-essentials-2015-extension-keeps.html). You need to uninstall the extension twice before reinstalling it.

Comment: In case it doesn't come with default VS2015 settings or Resharper 2016.1.1 I did not installed anything extra.
Plus I can see those lines in some .aspx files as I just find out.

Comment: Its just an extension/plugin which you can download anytime. You want help on how to download?

Comment: No thank you. I think I have all I need it just doesn't work on some files.

Comment: Hmm yes, I have heard of this problem where the WE extension disables everytime on VS restart which may be the issue. [Here is the step by step solution](https://david.gardiner.net.au/2015/11/web-essentials-2015-extension-keeps.html). Answer upated

Comment: I don't have extension witch such a name. Closest to it is Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools. Well I have auto update enabled so in case it is really part of extension it could be the case.

Comment: Maybe thats the reason, earlier your VS had those extensions by default but now you need to download them separately.